# Cambria bold fonts not working with nodejs PDFmake plugin

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I am trying to generate PDF using PDFmake in node.js but its not working when try to make some text of PDF bold it works with regular case but not with bold font it is showing the blank space when i use Cambria BOLD but works fine with Helvatica BOLD. Cambria fonts are installed following is my code

```
var fonts = {
                              Cambria: {
                                    //normal: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                                    //bold: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                                    //  italics: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                                    //bolditalics: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'
                                    normal: 'assets/fonts/Cambria.ttf',
                                    bold: 'assets/fonts/Cambria_Bold.ttf',
                                    italics: 'assets/fonts/Cambria_Bold_Italic.ttf',
                                    bolditalics: 'assets/fonts/Cambria_Italic.ttf'
                                },

                                CambriaBold: {
                                    //normal: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                                    //bold: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                                    //  italics: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                                    //bolditalics: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'
                                    normal: 'assets/fonts/Cambria.ttf',
                                    bold: 'assets/fonts/Cambria_Bold.ttf',
                                    italics: 'assets/fonts/Cambria_Bold_Italic.ttf',
                                    bolditalics: 'assets/fonts/Cambria_Italic.ttf'


                                }
                            };


header: {

                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            alignment: 'justify',
                                            font:'CambriaBold',
                                            bold:true
                                        },

                                        simplefont: {
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            font: 'Cambria'

                                        },

                                        boldfont: {
                                            fontSize: 11,
                                            font: 'Cambria',
                                            color:'black'

                                        },
                                        boldfontheader: {
                                            fontSize: 14    

                                        },
                                        boldfontsummary: {
                                            fontSize: 11,
                                            font: 'Cambria',
                                            color:'black',
                                            bold:true

                                        },
                                        normalMargin: {
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            alignment: 'justify',
                                            margin:[15,0,0,0],
                                            font: 'Cambria'
                                        }
```